# How to set Finder default view for new files / folders?

Tags: finder

When creating a new text files in a new folder, I noticed that the Finder's default view is the 'Icon' view.   As nice as that is, I would prefer that new folders / files be displayed in Finder in the 'List' view.

Is there a property that I can set to ensure that **future** folders & files area displayed in the preferred 'List' view?